# how to use gps with php and html for showing dynamic route

Tags: php, html, gps

i'm developing a web site with php and html-5, my plan is to show dynamic route between two locations on the given JPEG image, how can we do this, I have no idea about using GPS system with website, I'd like some help..

Thanks

Comment: [`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)

Comment: See the W3schools article linked. You pass this method a callback that will get the location as a parameter. `getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous because the user might have to approve geolocation first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice article here:

http://merged.ca/iphone/html5-geolocation

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( 

    function (position) {  

    // Did we get the position correctly?
    // alert (position.coords.latitude);

    // To see everything available in the position.coords array:
    // for (key in position.coords) {alert(key)}

    alert(position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude);

    }, 
    // next function is the error callback
    function (error)
    {
        switch(error.code) 
        {
            case error.TIMEOUT:
                alert ('Timeout');
                break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                alert ('Position unavailable');
                break;
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                alert ('Permission denied');
                break;
            case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                alert ('Unknown error');
                break;
        }
    }
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

see this W3Schools article: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

```
if(!navigator.geolocation){
  //the browser does not support geolocation
}else{
  (function getPosition(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      function (position){
        //use the coordinates
        balloon.style.left = (position.coords.latitude - latMin) * latScale;
        balloon.style.top = (position.coords.longitude - longMin) * longScale;
        //requery the position after a set time
        setTimeout(getPosition,1000);
      }
    )
  })()
}
```